# C# merge field values if the ID's match

Tags: c#, .net, list, merge

How do i match 2 objects in a list if their ID match, and their text doesn't?

my objects is added to a list:

```
List<MyObject> list = New List<MyObject>();
```

This could be my list (This is an object):

```
ID      Text
1       this is some text
2       text1
1       more text
1       a little more
2       text 2
3       XXX
```

Then i would like the result to be:

```
ID      Text
1       this is some text more text a little more
2       text1 text2
3       XXX
```

I've tried with a for in a for loop, but i just can figure it out..

```
for (int i = 0; i < OrderList.Count; i++)
        {
            bool existsMoreThanOnce = false;

            for (int j = i; j < OrderList.Count; j++)
            {
                duplicates.Add(OrderList[i]);
                if (OrderList[i].OrderNumber == OrderList[j].OrderNumber && OrderList[i].OrderText != OrderList[j].OrderText)
                {
                    if(!uniques.Contains(OrderList[j]))
                    {
                        duplicates.Add(OrderList[j]);
                        existsMoreThanOnce = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (existsMoreThanOnce == false)
            {
                uniques.Add(OrderList[i]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What code are you using to do it at the moment?

Comment: y did this question got voted down?

Comment: hey Mathias what are the properties in MyObject? ID(int) and Text(string)?

Comment: hmm i actually thinks the id is a string.. and the text is also a string, if necessary i can change the id to int.

Answer (score 1):

First I create a class

```
public class Items
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public Items(int id, string text)
    {
        ID = id;
        Text = text;
    }
}
```

Now I the logic of my code is

```
List<Items> objItems = new List<Items>();
        objItems.Add(new Items(1,"Rahul"));
        objItems.Add(new Items(2, "Rohit"));
        objItems.Add(new Items(1, "Kumar"));
        objItems.Add(new Items(2, "Verma"));
        List<Items> objNew = new List<Items>(); //it will hold result
        string str = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < objItems.Count; i++)
        {
            if (objItems[i].ID > 0)
            {
                str = objItems[i].Text;
                for (int j = i + 1; j < objItems.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (objItems[i].ID == objItems[j].ID)
                    {
                        str += objItems[j].Text + " ";
                        objItems[j].ID = -1;
                    }
                }
                objNew.Add(new Items(objItems[i].ID, str));
            }
        }
```

ObjNew object contains the required output.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with LINQ's `GroupBy`.

```
var output = input.GroupBy(i => i.ID)
                  .Select(i => new { ID = i.Key, 
                                   Text = String.Join(" ", 
                                        i.Select(x => x.Text).ToArray()) });
```

Comment: how do I use the GroupBy? 
i can't say: MyList.Groupby

Comment: do you have `using System.Linq` at the top?

Comment: @Blam theres no `System.Text.Linq` namespace. The assembly is `System.Core`.

Comment: Daniel, I've added it, and now I'm getting this error: 
The best overloaded method match for string.join(string, params object[]) has some invalid arguments

Comment: Try changing `String.Join(i)` to `String.Join(" ", i.ToArray())`

Comment: var result = OrderList.GroupBy(i => i.OrderNumber)
                .Select(i => new { ID = i.Key, Text = String.Join(" ", i.ToArray()) }); 

this

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = list1.Concat(list2)
                .GroupBy(x => x.ID)
                .Where(g => g.GroupBy(x=>x.Text).Count() > 1)
                .Select(x => x.Key)
                .ToList();
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Can you add some description why it works like this?

Comment: well.. can u base the answer on only one list?

Comment: @Mathias just remove `.Concat(list2)`. Now you have only one list: `list1`

Answer (score 0):

First i created a class to hold your list

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

then i inserted the dummy values into it

```
List<MyObject> obj = new List<MyObject>
{
     new MyObject{ID=1, Text="this is some text"},
     new MyObject{ID=2, Text="text1"},
     new MyObject{ID=1, Text="more text"},
     new MyObject{ID=1, Text="a little more"},
     new MyObject{ID=2, Text="text 2"},
     new MyObject{ID=3, Text="XXX"}
};

List<MyObject> obj2 = new List<MyObject>(); //this list will hold your output
//the linq query will filter out the uniques ids.
var uniqueIds = (from a in obj select new { a.ID, a.Text }).GroupBy(x => x.ID).ToList();
//then iterated through all the unique ids to merge the texts and list them under the unique ids.
int id=0;
foreach (var item in uniqueIds)
{
    string contText = "";
    for (int j = 0; j < item.Count(); j++)
    {
        contText += item.ElementAt(j).Text + " ";
        id = item.ElementAt(j).ID;
    }

    obj2.Add(new MyObject { ID = id, Text = contText });               
 }
```

the list obj2 will have your desired output.